# Ajax.BeginForm using ASP.NET MVC 3 - Nothing Happens

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

All I need to do is create a simple search page that displays results in a partial view.  I have a search text box and a search submit button. I followed a tutorial I found online that seems very easy and quick to implement, but I am missing something here.  When I click the search button nothing happens.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or missing would be greatly appreciated.

I include the following script files in the main layout page

```
    @Script("jquery-1.5.1.min.js")
    @Script("modernizr-1.7.min.js")
    @Script("jquery-ui.min.js")
    @Script("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
    @Script("jquery.validate.min.js")
    @Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")

    @helper Script(string scriptName)
    {
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/" + scriptName)" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    }
```

The main search view is called AdminMenu.  This is listed under a Area in my project called Admin.

[image]

The following code in my main view

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdminSearch", "AdminMenu", new {area = "Admin"}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResults"}))
{
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}

<div id="searchResults">

</div>
```

Code in my partial view _adminSearch

```
<div id="searchResults">
    <div class="entitybox">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                Model,
                defaultSort: "Name", canPage: false
                );
        }

        @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "_tableGrid",
            columns: grid.Columns
                (
                    grid.Column("Name", "Name", item => @Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "SelectRecord", new { controller = "Menu", agencyKey = item.Id, name = item.Name }))
                )
           )

    </div>
</div>
```

Code for the Controller

```
public class AdminMenuController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult AdminMenu()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult AdminSearch(string q)
        {

            Records results = AgencyBusiness.GetAdminSearch(q);
            return PartialView("_adminSearch", results);

        }

    }
```

When the search button is clicked nothing happens.  If you put a break point on the AdminSearch method in the controller class it never gets hit.

Thanks in advance for your time.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a javascript error.  Are you sure that all scripts are being loaded properly?  Are there any javascript errors being thrown by the browser?  Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox with Firebug can provide the insight into these questions (if you didn't already know :) )

Comment: No javascript errors are detected in IE, Chrome, or Firefox

Comment: If you perform an Ajax.BeginForm in your view, should there be any form text or scripts added when viewing the page html source.  All I get are the input and div tags viewing the page source.  It is like they are out there all alone, not linked up to anything.

Comment: Unsure about that, but I would expect at least a Form tag with your inputs, since the AJAX would be serializing the form and submitting to the form action.  I haven't really used this since it was the MS ajax form, so I can't really answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.  Odd thing.  I used a shared view to show the current user at the top of the view using the following line.

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_LoginBar.cshtml")
```

The main problem was that @Ajax.BeginForm function did not output any form tags to the browser.
By using the following line instead, the form tags appeared in the HTML source and the ajax function worked.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LoginBar.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a div called "searchResults" in both your main view and partial view.  Ajax is probably getting confused.

Comment: I removed the div tag in the partial view, but that was not the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the MicrosoftAjax.js file when using Ajax.BeginForm.

Comment: I included the MicrosoftAjax.js file.  Nothing changes.

Comment: @dretzlaff17 - you also need MicrosoftMvcAjax.js - MicrosoftAjax.js must come before MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, both have to come after jquery